# Nested Polymer Components Content Issue

Tags: javascript, polymer, shadow-dom

foo.html:

```
<link rel="import" href="bar.html">
<dom-module id="p-foo">
    <template>
        <p-bar>
            <content select=".myContent"></content>
        </p-bar>
    </template>
    <script>
        Polymer( {
            is: 'p-foo',
        } )
    </script>
</dom-module>
```

bar.html:

```
<dom-module id="p-bar">
    <template>
        bar open
        <content select=".myContent"></content>
        bar closed
    </template>
    <script>
        Polymer( {
            is: 'p-bar',
        } )
    </script>
</dom-module>
```

demo.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>    
        ...
        <link rel="import" href="foo.html">
    </head>
    <body>
        <p-foo><div class="myContent"><strong>hello</strong></div></p-foo>
    </body>
</html>
```

The expected output:

```
bar open
hello
bar closed
```

What I sometimes get:

```
bar open
bar closed
hello
```

The error I am getting is not 100% reproducible. It only happens a percentage of the time I refresh the page. It also appears that the more complicated the content is the higher chance of the error occurring.

It seems that polymer tries to select `.myContent` before the `bar` component is has completely rendered.

Comment: Some error in the example you pasted above. Ignoring the fact that an element cannot be named as `foo` and `bar` (missing hypen `-`) `bar open` and `bar closed` will be printed as you have used `selector` in content tag. Can you please provide some more relevant example to reproduce the problem as i've not been able to do so even once.

Comment: @a1626 I think you mean that `bar open` and `bar closed` will *not* be printed because it's not being distributed to any `<content>`

Comment: @TomaszPluskiewicz yes. With current code `content` tag will only look for things with class `myContent` and render it. Anything other than that it will ignore.

Comment: I messed up the example, I updated the example, `bar open` and `bar closed` were not supposed to be inside the `<content>` tag. That was not the issue though. I still don't know why it does this.

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to register your new custom elements with a call to `Polymer()`.
2. Also, as already stated in comments, your custom elements need to contain an hypen. For example: `<p-foo>`and `<p-bar>`.

foo.html:

```
<link rel="import" href="bar.html">
<dom-module id="p-foo">
    <template>
        <p-bar>
            <content select=".myContent"></content>
        </p-bar>
    </template>
    <script>
        Polymer( {
            is: 'p-foo',
        } )
    </script>
</dom-module>
```

bar.html:

```
<dom-module id="p-bar">
    <template>
        bar open
        <content select=".myContent"></content>
        bar closed
    </template>
    <script>
        Polymer( {
            is: 'p-bar',
        } )
    </script>
</dom-module>
```

demo.html:

```
    <head>    
         ...
        <link rel="import" href="foo.html">
    </head>
    <body>
        <p-foo><div class="myContent"><strong>hello</strong></div></p-foo>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Apologies, but those were just oversights in the example but the bug still occurs. If I make many many more content selectors and also make the content in those selects more complicated (as in my elements etc.) the likelihood of reproducing the error on refresh goes up drastically. It appears to be some kind of race condition where if the page fully renders before Polymer can make those content selections then it just throws everything in those content elements to the bottom of the element.

Comment: The example above works perfectly and it is not a question of race condition. Does it work for you with Chrome at least? Can you provide enough information to reproduce the bug?

Comment: like I said, its a very small percentage of the time where it messes up. If you make the example more complicated (adding a lot more html) you chances of reproducing the error are much greater. If you make it very complicated I think it's like 1 in 4 refreshes will reproduce the bug.

Comment: Does your issue appears with Chrome?

Comment: Yes, Chrome, and I believe every other browser I've tested. But I Chrome for sure.