# Disqus comments don't work in a polymer custom element

Tags: javascript, polymer, custom-element, polymer-elements, html5-template

I don't know how to make a disqus comments code to work inside of my custom elements.

#### Structure of my site:

| `index.html`
--------\ `my-app.html` (custom element)
----------------\ `my-testView1.html` (custom element)
----------------\ `my-testView2.html` (custom element)

I need to put disqus comments inside `my-testView1.html` and `my-testView2.html`

#### Structure of `index.html`:

```
 <body>
   <my-app>
      <div class="disqusClass1" id="disqus_thread"></div>
      <div class="disqusClass2" id="disqus_thread"></div>
   <my-app>
</body>
```

#### Structure of `my-app.html`:

```
 <iron-pages>
      <my-testView1 name="testView"><content select=".disqusClass1"></content></my-testView1>
      <my-testView2 name="testView2"><content select=".disqusClass2"></content></div></my-testView2>
    </iron-page‌​s>
```

#### Structure of `my-testView1.html` :

```
<template>
  <content select=".disqusClass1"></content>
</template>
```

#### Structure of `my-testView2.html` :

```
<template>
  <content select=".disqusClass2"></content>
</template>
```

#### The disqus div

I put the div of the disqus comments inside `<my-app>` on the `index.html` so that chrome could find it. It **can't** find it if I put it inside `<my-testView1>` like that:

page `my-app.html`

```
<iron-pages>
  <my-testView1 name="testView"><div id="disqus_thread"></div></my-testView1>
  <my-testView2 name="testView2"><div id="disqus_thread"></div></my-testView2>
</iron-page‌​s>
```

because the my-app.html is a custom element itself and it won't let chrome to find it. So I  had to put it outside of the shadow dom (the `index.html` page)

#### Javacript code on the pages `my-testView1.html` and `my-testView2.html`look like this:

```
<dom-module id="my-testView1">
  <template>
   ...
        <content></content>
   ...
 </template>

  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'my-testView1',

      ready: function () 
          {    
             // DEFAULT DISQUS CODE (I changed real URLs though):        
             var disqus_config = function () {
             this.page.url = 'https://www.example.com/testView1'; // Replace PAGE_URL with your page's canonical URL variable
             this.page.identifier = '/testView1'; 
             // this.page.title = 'Test View';
             };

            (function() { 
            var d = document, s = d.createElement('script');
            s.src = '//myChannelName.disqus.com/embed.js';
            s.setAttribute('data-timestamp', +new Date());
            (d.head || d.body).appendChild(s);
            })();
        }
     });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

#### Result

Comments appears only on one of these `my-testView1.html` `my-testView2.html` at the time. I need 1 disqus thread on **my-testView1.html** and another disqus thread on **my-testView2.html**

Maybe it's because of routing. Disqus console message says that I need to use ajax method https://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/472107-using-disqus-on-ajax-sites Unfortunately I could not make it work when I replaced the javascript code above with the code from the example:

```
  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'my-testView1',

      ready: function () 
          {    
                 var disqus_shortname = 'myDisqusChannelId';
                 var disqus_identifier = '/testView1';
                 var disqus_url = 'http://example.com/testView1';
                 var disqus_config = function () { 
                   this.language = "en";
                 };

                 (function() {
                     var dsq = document.createElement('script'); dsq.type = 'text/javascript'; dsq.async = true;
                     dsq.src = 'http://' + disqus_shortname + '.disqus.com/embed.js';
                     (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(dsq);
                 })();

                 var reset = function (newIdentifier, newUrl) {
                     DISQUS.reset({
                         reload: true,
                         config: function () {
                             this.page.identifier = newIdentifier;
                             this.page.url = newUrl;
                         }
                     });
                 };
        }
     });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

inside both custom elements (changing `disqus_identifier` and `disqus_url` correspondingly for each of them)

Comment: You probably don't really have to put the Disqus script in main document. See how I placed it inside element's template and bind the `channelName` property: http://jsbin.com/feqaqig/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Now that think of it, putting Disqus inside Polymer element is probably not a good idea at all. It will not work under Shadow DOM and I don't really see a benefit

Comment: @Supersharp I put an **UPDATE #1** in the question, if you have a free minute could you please check it out?

Comment: @TomaszPluskiewicz well, I have my site's pages as custom elements, and I wanted to put `script` of the disqus to some of those pages (custom elements). But as you said it won't work in shadow dom, and I'm a newbie so I don't really know how to implement it yet. Unfortunately there's no useful (for newbies) information about scripts inside of custom polymer elements in the polymer documentation

Comment: add the div twice and give them a different selection id

Comment: Like it is in the **Result** section of the question? I just tried and it doesn't work unfortunately.

Comment: No. Like in this example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39484400/4600982. But are you sure you can insert 2 disqus threads in one page?

Comment: Well I'm not sure if I can insert 2 disqus threads but since each custom element is placed in its own .html page I thought that would work. There's routing involved but..I don't know. Well I saw a console warning saying I have to put it as ajax and it gave me this link [link](https://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/472107-using-disqus-on-ajax-sites) so I clicked **example DISQUS.reset recipe** there and replaced the current javascript code with that example presented there on each of the custom element pages and now I see **We were unable to load Disqus** on the place of the comments

Comment: Okay, so I need to add `select=""`? As it shown in the **Result** section I have these ids there `disqus_thread` and `disqus_thread2` Do I need to make <content> look like this: in one custom element `<content select="#disqus_thread">` and `<content select="#disqus_thread2">` in another for both custom element pages and the page in between (my-app.html)?

Comment: Your div must have the name disqus_thread (exactly) to work. So you can only have one in your page. Pût it one level  higher in your hierachy and follow the advice of the link you provided

Comment: Thanks to you it looks like the only problem left there is the javascript of the disqus itself. I'm trying to transform that javascript in a way that disqus example suggest, but so far no luck though. Ehhh..web dev is hard, man

Comment: the DISQUS.resest() method should be called every time the view (either 1 or 2) is displayed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is due to the fact that the *disqus* library can't find the `<div id="disqus_thread">` element.

It's because this element is inside a Shadow DOM (and that's why it works fine in Firefox which doesn't implement real Shadow DOM).

3 possible solutions:

1. Don't use Shadow DOM with your Polymer elements.
2. Don't put the `#disqus_thread` element in a Polymer element (insert it in the normal DOM).
3. Use `<content>` in your `<template>`, and the `#disqus_thread` element inside the polymer tag  to make it availabe to the library:

*In the custom elements:*

```
<template>
   //HTML code here
   <content></content>
</template>
```

*In the HTML page where you insert the custom element:*

```
<my-app>
   <my-testView>
      <div id="disqus_thread"></div>
   </my-testView>
</my-app>
```

The `<div>` will be *revealed* at the place where the (nested) `<content>` tags are placed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have this structure `index.html --/ my-app.html (custom element) --/ my-testView.html (custom element)`. So it's custom element inside of custom element. So do I have to put `<div id="disqus_thread"></div>` inside index.html `<body>` basically? I just did that and I also put `<content></content>` to the place it needs to be on the page of my `my-testView.html` custom element. And I can see disqus now on all the pages fixed on top of the page. But It didn't go to the `<content>` tag. Oh man, it's really suck to be a newbie in web development..

Comment: if you have nested custom elements, you have to add content elements in all the custom element templates. Don't apply 2 differents solutions in the same time.

Comment: okay. What I did now is I just put `<div id="disqus_thread"></div>` inside `body` tag on **index.html** and I added <content></content> inside `<iron-pages><my-testView name="testView"><content></content></my-testView></iron-pages>` to the custom element **my-app.html** and I also added  <content></content> to the custom element **my-testView.html** on the place it needs to be there, but  I just don't understand how it knows that `<div id="disqus_thread"></div>` inside `body` on the **index.html** need to go to the `<content></content>` on **my-testView.html** What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: the `div` should be inside your custom element and the `content` inside the `template`! as in the example above

Comment: It won't find it then, because the `my-app.html` itself if the custom element. I rewrote my question and updated it so it would be easier to see what is nested and what isn't, showing how it looks. I understand you probably sick of this question already but If you happen to know the answer I'll appreciate if you add something to it, thanks a lot

Comment: actually your rewritten question is a new one

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to give another possible solution to using Disqus comments in Polymer. The main problem is the inability to use Disqus with elements in the shadow dom because they are hidden. So how can we make a shadow dom element visible? We can pass it down the component hierarchy from the index.html of the application.

To expose an element structure your html like this:

```
index.html
<polymer-app>
  <div id="disqus_thread">
</polymer-app>
```

In Polymer App:

```
<dom-module id="polymer-app">
  <template>
      <slot></slot>
  <template>
</dom-module>
```

Slot is where the #disqus_thread will show. And you can pass it further down to other components, inside polymer-app.

```
<dom-module id="polymer-app">
  <template>
    <my-page>
      <slot></slot>
    </my-page>
  <template>
</dom-module>
```

Note: This is code is just an example. Don't try to copy and paste, it won't run.