# Dynamically insert content tag

Tags: javascript, polymer, web-component, shadow-dom

I want to use the `<content>` tag dynamically (On demand).

**Ex:**

Parent:

```
<parent>
    <child>
        <grand-child></grand-child>
    </child>
<parent>
```

Child:

```
<child>
    <content></content>
</child>
```

The above hierarchy would place the grand child inside the child, but I want to insert the content provided by the parent dynamically.

For ex:

1. Grand Parent is a tab
2. Child is a table
3. Grand Child is a chart

On clicking on the row of the table I want to display the chart below the row. But the type of the element has to be passed from the tab.

Is there a way to achieve this?

**What I tried:**

1. Dynamically created the content tag using `document.createElement("content");` on row click event handler. This creates the content tag but not its contents. I guess that will be available only at the template render time.

Comment: I tried creating the content tag on row click but of no use. I trying to figure out if there is a way to hold the contents somewhere so that I can reuse without using the content tag in the template.

Comment: In what way is the "*type of the element...passed from the tab*"? I'd suggest it would be better to show a genuine ("*[MCVE]*") snippet of the code you're using to illustrate what should happen, show the HTML you're starting with, explain the user-interaction and show the expected result/output HTML/DOM. Also, please show the code you tried (this may help show what your intent is, but don't rely on it to do so), that way we can see with some surety that we're not just writing your code for you.

Comment: It is, the grand child could be a chart or a table or some html and the table  (child) is generic. So it should be passed from the grand parent only. I need to render it on table (child) row click.

Comment: Forgive me for not providing an example. Since its kinda complicated to create a sample, I didn't. I'll try to do it and post it asap.

Comment: Did you try to hide/display the content element by setting its hidden attribute?

Comment: I don't want to do that as the content might have multiple API calls within itself. That could be a performance hit. On demand would be better

Comment: Here is an exempe with nested content: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39484400/4600982